# Select sun Java version 7 via command line in linux

Tags: java, eclipse, terminal

I have openjdk and the sun version installed, how do i choose the sun version via command line?

I want this for eclipse ptp.

Comment: Do you mean the JVM that is used to run Eclipse or the JVM that Eclipse uses when it runs Java projects?

Comment: jvm that is used to run eclipse, because i want to run photran.

Comment: The `-vm <path>` answers are the appropriate ones in that case

Answer (score 0):

Just explicitly call the right java executable in your command line.

i.e. `<path to sun java>\java -jar test.jar`

Comment: no i mean how to make jdk1.7 be used as default, not for a particular project

Comment: The default for the system or when starting Eclipse?

Comment: default preferably or just eclipse if that's easier to setup

Comment: @Tim B, i thought that would be the easiest way, just copy paste a command into there

Answer (score 0):

You can do two things if you want to start Eclipse in Sun Java.

1. Change your PATH variable to have the Sun Java Bin Directory before Open JDK.

   export PATH=Path_to_Sun_Java/bin:$PATH

   And then start eclipse from the same terminal which will use Sun Java
2. Edit the eclipse.ini file and specify the `-vm` option

   -vm Path_to_Sun_Java/bin/java

Answer (score 0):

For Eclipse you can start it with the -vm path_to_vm/bin/java option.
If you want to set it for the system, that depends on your OS. Most Linux distributions have a tool that switches system VMs for your (sets PATH and JAVA_HOME accordingly). Maybe setting both in your ˜/.profile on Linux or user environment variable on Windows is already good enough for your purposes?

Comment: ok, i installed the Java SE Development Kit 7u45 on fedora 18 whilst i already had java version "1.7.0_25" OpenJDK Runtime Environment installed. So which tool will I need to just make the switch painlessly?

Comment: If you used the Fedora package manager to install both versions, then google for "fedora switch java version" and you should find what you need. If you "installed" the two versions manually, then you need to make the changes to PATH and JAVA_HOME manually.

Answer (score 0):

if for eclipse only but for all eclipse Projects then :

from the dropdown menu window->preferences, then **java->installed jre**, select your jre, if not there, just browse your system  and locate the path to Oracle JRE/JDK

, if for all your OS, here links for linux:

Suse Linux: 
http://www.freetechie.com/blog/installing-oracle-sun-java-jrejdk-1-7-update-7-on-opensuse-12-2-x86_64/

Ubuntu:
http://www.webupd8.org/2012/01/install-oracle-java-jdk-7-in-ubuntu-via.html

Comment: i went to window->preferences, but i don't see installed jre there, which option are you referring to?

Comment: sorry my bad, see update please! : window->preferences, then java->installed jre

Answer (score 0):

You can try this [script](https://github.com/flexiondotorg/oab-java6) which makes everything for you or follow steps manually with [nice explanation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/183867/how-do-i-update-oracle-java-7-jdk-and-jre).